# AWS API Gateway Lambda development with a custom library in python: How to deploy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, aws-toolkit

I'm developing an API Gateway AWS with PyCharm in python. I'm using AWS Dev Tools and I've started to create Hello World template, which works fine.
Then now I will add a python module that I developed and I want to deploy it to make it available to lambda functions.
That's the project structure:

```
├── __init__.py
├── library_common
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── configuration.py
│   └── encryption.py
├── events
│   └── event.json
├── keepalive_functions
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── app.py
│   └── requirements.txt
├── requirements.txt
├── samconfig.toml
├── template.yaml
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── integration
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_api_gateway.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── unit
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_handler.py
```

Basically, I want to use functions in library_common when I call lambda function in keepalive_functions.

Next template.yaml text:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  entry365anchor

  Sample SAM Template for entry365anchor

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  GetKeepalive:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: keepalive_functions/
      Handler: app.get_keepalive
      Runtime: python3.8
      Events:
        PutResource:
          Type: Api # More info about API Event Source: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api
          Properties:
            Path: /v1/keepalive
            Method: get
```

Running method I incurred in this error:

{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'entry365common'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your question? You have explained what difficulties you have, what error messages you get?

Comment: It can't use the module. After building this is the message:
{"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'entry365common'", "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError", "stackTrace": []}